# What does the line x=!y mean

Tags: c++

Here is a part of code

```
int main()
{
    int x=5,y=10;
    if(x=!y)
    {
        cout<<"h";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"p";
    }
    getch();
}
```

The output was `p`, please explain, how the code works and the meaning of `x=!y`.

Comment: It's an assignment statement, probably an error, assigning `!y`, which has the value zero, because `y` is non-zero so its Boolean complement is zero, to `x`.

Comment: It's a boolean assignment.  If "y" is "true", then "x" becomes "false".  "false" is always the integer "0"; "true" is any non-zero integer (typically -1).  Of course, it *could* just be a typo: maybe the author meant "if (x != y) {...}"..,  Q: Can you ask?

Comment: This is important that x=!y is treated as "x equals not of y", But x !=y is treated as (x not equals to y) condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a typo that produces valid code.  Expanding it helps--

```
if (x = (!y))
```

Since y is 10, `!y` == `0`, and assignments themselves produce a value.  In particular the value of `x = 0` is 0, so the test evaluates to 0 and that's why you get the result.

But this is a crazy thing to write in this context, presumably what was, or what should have been intended was

```
if (x != y)
```

I.e., not-equals.

Answer (score 7):

`x=!y` is an assignment.

`x` is being assigned the value of `!y` expression, which is a [logical "NOT" operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k6w8551.aspx). This operation returns `true` if the operand is zero, or `false` otherwise. The value `true` becomes `1` when assigned back to `int`; `false` becomes zero.

In C and C++ it is OK to use assignment expressions inside `if` conditionals and other control statements, such as `for` and `while` loops. The value being assigned is used to evaluate the condition, and the assignment itself is performed as a side effect. In this case, the condition is `!y`.

Comment: Possibly worh noting that assignment returns assigned value, which is then used by `if`